# Who wrote the poem that begins, "The Yeti, experts will attest . . ."

Tags: poetry, identification-request

> The Yeti, experts will attest, is physically unkempt at best.
>   And due to this may go for weeks, alone amidst the snowy steeps.

(Goes on to tell how he is looking for his "yet unmet counterpart".)

Comment: Hi - I've had to vote to close this because as phrased the question isn't very helpful - who "knows" this poem is not a question with a clear, concise answer. However, I suspect that might not be what you meant to ask, and if so a quick edit should clear it up.

Comment: Could that last word be "peaks" instead of "steeps"? That would be a better rhyme for "weeks".

Comment: @user14111 Sure but "who knows" is not an identification question. "Who wrote" would be. Hence my suggestion to edit

Comment: @user14111 writing a title is as hard as writing a question. While Math.SE accepts that kind of titles, it doesn't mean that's a [good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/241919). Title should reflect the core question as clear as possible. "What is the title of the poem" or "Who wrote this poem" is, but "Who knows" is not what the asker really wants.

Comment: @user14111 That's unfair. I'm not being hyper-literal - I'm just wary of presuming that I know what the OP wants.